# Return Boolean value from Android AlertDialog function

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my app i have a function that checks the entered text from a displayed AlertDialog with an input text. If the text is equal to a string variable, return True, else return False, and catch this resulting value to continue conditional code.

But it seems its a little difficult to do this as i've read in other posts asking how to solve the same problem.

I've already done this:

```
private boolean checkAdministratorPassword() {
   final enterPasswordResult[0] = false;

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    alert.setTitle("Confirm action");
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    alert.setMessage("Enter administrator pass to continue");

    final EditText input = new EditText(mContext);
    input.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            String strPass = input.getEditableText().toString();
            if (strPass.length() == 0) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
            if (strPass.equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.ADMIN_PASS)) {
                enterPasswordResult[0] = true;
                dialog.cancel();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Invalid pass..!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    return enterPasswordResult[0];
    }
```

And i call the function this way:

```
If ( checkAdministratorPassword() == True ){
  //true conditions
}
```

But the problem is that the check function doesnt wait for the result to continue with the code, it just continue by itself and i dont get the appropiate behavior.

Comment: Is the "If" and "True" a copy/paste error or is that really how it is in your code?

Comment: `checkAdministratorPassword(new Runnable(){ public void run() { /*code for true*/ }}, new Runnable(){ public void run() { /*code for false*/ }})` ... `checkAdministratorPassword(Runnable trueCode, Runnable falseCode)` in onClick of alert do `trueCode.run();` if password is ok and `falseCode.run();` if not

Comment: This is a question about the structure of your app: I think it's better to call desired function inside the positive button onClick listener

Comment: @codeMagic: yes, its just a copy/paste error. in my code i have "if" and "true" correctly. thank you-

Comment: you can try this solution check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53946103/10288513)

Comment: you can check this solution :
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53946103/10288513)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you're trying to handle an async event in the logcal flow of your program. You can do this if you make the `Dialog` it's own class and use an `Interface` to callback to your host activity. Check out the documentation on [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

```
public interface PasswordCheckListener{
    public void valid(boolean check);
}

private static class PasswordDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private PasswordCheckListener listener;

    public static PaswordDialog newInstance(PasswordCheckListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }       

    @Override    
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Put your dialog creation code here
    }

    private checkAdminPassword(){
        //Whatever your check passowrd code is
        listener.valid(result);
    }
}
```

I realize I didn't implement all the code for you but that's the general idea. By using an interface you can call back to your host `Activity` or `Fragment` when the user enters the password and presses submit. You can then handle the event as it happens, rather than having to deal with it in your program flow.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers!! i've found the right way to achieve this problem by creating an Activity whith theme "Theme.Dialog", an input text and two buttons (Accept, Cancel), i start this activity for result asking the user to enter the administrator pass to continue, checking the string and then returning again to onActivityResult() from previous activity with the correct information to proceed.